# LWC launch URL from apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I'm struggling to find the best way to accomplish this - any suggested are appreciated! I have an LWC for a community page that will have a button to launch an external URL. The URL needs to be generated **when they push the button** from the apex class due to a time sensitive URL generation. I've tried a few different ways and have been unable to get it to launch.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getURL from '@salesforce/apex/lwcController.getURL';

export default class NavToHome extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

   navigateToWebPage() {
        // Navigate to a URL

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: getURL
            }
        },
        true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
      );
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="NavToHome" icon-name="custom:custom96">
        <lightning-button
            label="Go to Home"
            class="slds-var-m-around_medium"
            onclick={navigateToWebPage}
        ></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I've kept it pretty basic for demo purposes but this isn't launching the URL that is returned from getURL method of the apex class. Thoughts or better ways to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're close, just get the value then use it:

```
async navigateToWebPage() {
    // Navigate to a URL
    let url = await getURL();
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: { url }
    },
    true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
  );
}
```

The `await` keyword waits for the URL to be returned, and the `async` keyword is necessary in any function that uses `await`.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox !! That does get me one step closer. What happens now, however, which is new behavior is in my community it tries to append the returned URL at the end of the community URL and does not launch in a separate window. Before it was launching correctly in new tab (this is what I need). Ideas on how to fix that? I'm doing some digging now...

Comment: @EMC Not sure. I don't do much work in communities.

Comment: I get the same behavior internally on a record page, i.e. https://.../lightning/r/Account/0014x000006WJSTAA4/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Comment: @EMC I'll try to replicate the issue this evening, and get back with you.

Comment: @EMC Can't seem to replicate it; it works fine in my org as a App Page.

Comment: Thanks for trying. In my apex class I was using EncodingUtil.urlEncode(URL, 'UTF-8') and returning that to the LWC. I think that may have caused the issue; when I removed that and passed only a string it worked. But I think for my specific implementation it will need to be encoded due to the formatting. The text could have spacing or special characters.

Comment: @EMC You'll need to encode only the parts that need encoding. You definitely should not encode the entire URL. I would use a PageReference in Apex to build your URL correctly with escaped parameters, and return the plain string back to LWC for consumption.